# How can I change the name of Remote Desktop in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, remote-desktop, vino

I am using Gnome Classic DE with Ubuntu 12.04. The Vino VNC server is functioning perfectly but it annoyingly advertises itself on the LAN as "(user)'s remote desktop on (server)".

I've looked at `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Vino` and there doesn't appear to be an easy way to change this in Vino's settings. Seen this asked a few other places around the net with no answers so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: note: installed tightvncserver as a workaround.  it's a bit faster and doesn't advertise itself at all on the LAN.  not exactly what i wanted but for me it's an improvement.